# stream_select timeout on newly opened socket

Tags: php, sockets, thrift

I use thrift php client to connect to java thrift server. But got the error of

```
TSocket: timed out writing 78 bytes from 10.0.1.151:1234
```

I dig into the php source of thrift and find it was caused from timeout on function  `stream_select`.

```
/**
 * Write to the socket.
 *
 * @param string $buf The data to write
 */
public function write($buf)
{
    $null = null;
    $write = array($this->handle_);

    // keep writing until all the data has been written
    while (TStringFuncFactory::create()->strlen($buf) > 0) {
        // wait for stream to become available for writing
        $writable = @stream_select($null, $write, $null, $this->sendTimeoutSec_, $this->sendTimeoutUsec_);
        if ($writable > 0) {
            // write buffer to stream
            $written = @stream_socket_sendto($this->handle_, $buf);
            if ($written === -1 || $written === false) {
                throw new TTransportException('TSocket: Could not write '.TStringFuncFactory::create()->strlen($buf).' bytes '.
                        $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
            }
            // determine how much of the buffer is left to write
            $buf = TStringFuncFactory::create()->substr($buf, $written);
        } elseif ($writable === 0) {
            throw new TTransportException('TSocket: timed out writing '.TStringFuncFactory::create()->strlen($buf).' bytes from '.
                    $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
        } else {
            throw new TTransportException('TSocket: Could not write '.TStringFuncFactory::create()->strlen($buf).' bytes '.
                    $this->host_.':'.$this->port_);
        }
    }
}
```

That means the socket was blocked and was not able to write. But the socket is just open and should not be blocked. I try select immediately after `pfsockopen`

```
if ($this->persist_) {
  $this->handle_ = @pfsockopen($this->host_,
                               $this->port_,
                               $errno,
                               $errstr,
                               $this->sendTimeoutSec_ + ($this->sendTimeoutUsec_ / 1000000));
} else {
  $this->handle_ = @fsockopen($this->host_,
                              $this->port_,
                              $errno,
                              $errstr,
                              $this->sendTimeoutSec_ + ($this->sendTimeoutUsec_ / 1000000));
}

// Connect failed?
if ($this->handle_ === FALSE) {
  $error = 'TSocket: Could not connect to '.$this->host_.':'.$this->port_.' ('.$errstr.' ['.$errno.'])';
  if ($this->debug_) {
    call_user_func($this->debugHandler_, $error);
  }
  throw new TException($error);
}

$write = array($this->handle_);
$writable = @stream_select($null, $write, $null, $this->sendTimeoutSec_, $this->sendTimeoutUsec_);
if ($writable === 0) {
    die('123');
}
```

The result show that it is block right after it is opened!

When restart php-fpm, the error disappear for a while and come up again.

Here is the client code:

```
$socket = new TSocket('10.0.1.151', 1234, true); 
$framedSocket = new TFramedTransport($socket); 
$transport = $framedSocket;
$protocol = new TCompactProtocol($transport);   
$transport->open();
$client= new userservice\UserServiceProxyClient($protocol);  
$result = $client->findUser($id);
```

If I adjust the php-fpm configuration `pm.max_children` from 200 to 2, the error also disappear.

I tried increase timeout to 10 seconds and it timeout after 10 seconds.

Any idea for what's the cause of the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I modify the php thrift lib. Change from

```
$writable = @stream_select($null, $write, $null, $this->sendTimeoutSec_, $this->sendTimeoutUsec_);
```

to

```
$writable = 1;
```

And the same for read.

The problem get fixed.

That means the connection is established ( I even use tcpdump to confirm the tcp connection is established) and writable, but select timeout. Strange things!